Sudden whinning noise in 4th gear under acceleration. Bad bearing?
I have a Mk1 Golf/Rabbit (Cabriolet, 5 speed manual, 1.8lt).
I was driving last night and noticed a whinning noise suddenly develop when in 4th gear. This only occured under acceleration (coasting and clutch-in was fine).
All other gears sounded fine and the car drove fine otherwise.
Is this a bad bearing?

It sounds like the whining noise you’re experiencing in 4th gear under acceleration could indeed be related to a bearing issue, possibly the input shaft bearing or a specific gear bearing. Bearings can wear out over time, and their failure often manifests as noise when the drivetrain is under load, like during acceleration. Since the noise disappears when coasting or with the clutch engaged, it points to a load-bearing component rather than something related to the differential or clutch.
That being said, other potential causes could include:
Gear wear: If 4th gear is more worn compared to others, it may produce whining under load.
Synchro issues: Though less likely since shifting seems unaffected, a damaged synchronizer could also create noise.
Fluid level/quality: Make sure the gearbox oil is at the correct level and hasn't degraded. Low or contaminated oil can cause whining in specific gears.
It would be a good idea to have the gearbox checked out sooner rather than later, as a failing bearing can lead to further damage.

Thanks. Yeah looking under the car I noticed a transmission fluid leak. I replaced the fluid and the noise is now gone, but will need to replace the shaft seals at some point too.

Vw is KNOWN on their older golfs for having excessive play in the input shaft. Their recommended fix (or at least the one all the Vw techs actually perform) is to use a shim to reduce input shaft play which generally solves this whine.
As for why it only happens in 4th gear… well that boils down to transmission harmonics and loading of the input shaft.
